# Vue Router having both query and path properties

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

I have the need for a route which takes properties from both the path as well as the query, but I can not get it working:

```js
      {
        path: 'clients',
        component: () => import('pages/client/Index.vue'),
        props: route => ({ filter: route.query.filter }),
        children: [
          {
            path: ':clientId',
            props: route => ({ filter: route.query.filter, clientId: route.path.clientId }),
            component: () => import('pages/client/Index.vue')
          }
        ]
      }
```

I can get it to work, with either the query or the path props, but making both work seems to be impossible.

I also tried props: true which, if I understood the documentation should simply work, but it does not.  In my Component (Index.vue).  Itried definning the props in the following two ways:

```js
  props: {
    clientId: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    filter: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
```

```js
  props: {
    ...RouterLink.props
  },
```

Neither of them make a difference, it mainly depends on how I define the routes in router.js.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get both path and query props working at the same time on the same route?

Tia

Answer (score 0):

Here is your error:

props: route => ({ filter: route.query.filter, clientId: route.**path**.clientId })

You should use ***params*** instead of ***path***

props: route => ({ filter: route.query.filter, clientId: route.**params**.clientId })

Here is the solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-azs4wh?file=src/router.js

Docs: [Dynamic Route Matching with Params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)